# Hiding sensitive GET parameters from App Engine log

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging

I have a python app on App Engine. Every request's url is by default logged into the application log and can be later viewed by admins, for example:

[image]

Some of the GET requests in my app contain sensitive information. Is there a way to prevent App Engine from logging them? I still want the request to be logged, just without all or some of the parameters.

**Note:** I cannot make these requests using POST, as they are generated by a third party.

Comment: The first question would be how would you/the process know which data is sensitive?

Comment: @SteveBarnes Only specific urls contains sensitive data, and I know them all in advance.

Comment: The next question is is it your app that is doing the logging or is it the framework?

Comment: What you want isn't possible on App Engine.

Comment: You could encrypt the sensitive data

Comment: @Greg thanks. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: if you can't trust your admins, get better admins? :P

Comment: it's documented that app engine will log automatically for you. I also am unaware that you can turn it off (why would you?!)

Comment: @user2266449 lol :) it's not a matter of trust, just damage control. Also I have no reason to disable the logging completely.

Comment: and thinking about it, it would do you no good anyway even if you could hide this info. Some with admin rights can simply upload a new version of the application that logs the "sensitive" data somewhere else. Accept the fact that "admin" by definition means full access in this case.

Comment: The log format is explained in this post: http://blog.notdot.net/2011/06/Demystifying-the-App-Engine-request-logs I can't imagine the lack of configurability is something anyone would document... where would you stop? :)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do what you want to do. I would recommend filling a [Feature Request](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request). Make sure you spell out a good use case.

As a work around you can have the request go to another App that only you have access to. It then POSTs the data to your main app. It is not elegant or efficient but will do what you need.